# Logging IP, Browser, Operating System...etc

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a page what will log a plethora of user data for security purposes but am am unsure how best to do so.

Ideally I want all important stats for example their IP, their X-Forward IP, their browser, operating system and any other details I can get.

I've also got problems showing the variables in a php / html page as shown below:

```
<?php
$ip = <?= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$template = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
IP: <?= $ip ?>
IP: [IP]
</body>
</html>';

$template = str_replace('[IP]', $ip, $template);

echo $template;
?>
```

or

```
<?php
$ip = <?= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

echo $ip;
?>
```

Comment: thats all in the access logs, so process them.

Comment: You need to stop trying to open PHP tags (e.g. `<?=`) when you're already in a PHP block.

Comment: @Dagon, the access logs are incredibly hard to use / read / view, also I want it purposely for a specific page.

Comment: @MarkParnell that was just something I tried, I added another thing I've tried but I can't get anything to work :/

Comment: many scripts process the access logs, i wouldn't consider them hard. the majority of site stats programs used them before the likes of google analytics turned up

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way... but a 15 minute read through a basic php tutorial is probably in order. When talking about security, it is always best to thoroughly understand what you're doing.

Comment: @Dagon the Access logs are huge on the site, It's seriously not easy to read though them.

Comment: @mjayt I've spent the last hour on php.net trying to learn but am getting nowhere, I'm just looking for some snippits, some examples so that I can learn from them.

Comment: you don't, you let software read them(http://awstats.sourceforge.net/ et al) - but thats all up to you :-0

Comment: @Dagon so... any advice as to what software, some examples, links or anything? PHP like this may be simple to you but to me it's not...

Comment: i provided a link in my commnnet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something simple first:

```
<?php 
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo $ip;
?>
```

For a full list of SERVER superglobal variables, check this link http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$data = $_SERVER;
$IP = $data['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo "IP address is:" . $IP;
?>
```

There you go... now look up all the available $_SERVER values and use the ones you need.